# Why does rendering data with viewbag causes an error?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

why this error occur with .net mvc razor view

[image]

**Controller Code**

```
ViewBag.LowStock = db.StockInformations.Where(x => x.Qty <= x.MinStockLevel);
```

**View Code**

```
  @{
List<StockInformation> DangerLavel = (List<StockInformation>)ViewBag.LowStock;
var count = 0;
ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `LowStock` is a query, you cannot cast it to `List<StockInformation>`. Instead, you should call `ToList()` to it:

```
List<StockInformation> DangerLavel = ViewBag.LowStock.ToList();
```

The call retrieves the data from `DbQuery` after applying the filter, producing a list in memory.

Answer (score 2):

The error occurs because you are storing a DbQuery<StockInformation> and trying to get a List<StockInformation>.

The code below returns a DbQuery<StockInformation>.

```
db.StockInformations.Where(x => x.Qty <= x.MinStockLevel)
```

To fix it just call the ToList method:

```
db.StockInformations.Where(x => x.Qty <= x.MinStockLevel).ToList();
```

The ToList method will create a List based on the DbQuery returned from the Where method.